# Parsing csv files in d3.js version 4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I should preface by saying that I'm new to d3, and still learning the basics.

I'm trying to create a simple line graph with d3.js v4, but I'm having trouble parsing the data.
I get error problem parsing d attribute. I think my problem is the data in the csv file, as the comma separated number values are strings instead of numbers, and my code does not recognize that.

Here's a sample of cvs data of what I mean:

12/2021,"1,050"
1/11/2021,"1,091"
1/10/2021,"1,256"
1/9/2021,"1,276"
1/8/2021,"1,216"
1/7/2021,"1,224"
1/6/2021,"1,208"
1/5/2021,"1,100"
1/4/2021,"1,042"
1/3/2021,975
1/2/2021,775
1/1/2021,729
12/31/2020,736
12/30/2020,752
12/29/2020,732
12/28/2020,730
12/27/2020,684
12/26/2020,637
12/25/2020,627
12/24/2020,612

Here's the code:

```
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%m /%d/%Y");

d3.csv("EthereumPricesByYear2.csv")
.row(function(d){ return {Year: parseDate(d.Year), Price:Number(d.Price)}; })
.get(function(error,data){

  console.log(data);

  var height = 300;
  var width = 500;

  var max = d3.max(data,function(d){ return d.Price; });
  var minDate = d3.min(data,function(d){ return d.Year; });
  var maxDate = d3.max(data,function(d){ return d.Year; });

  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
              .domain([0,max])
              .range([height, 0]);
  var x = d3.scaleTime()
              .domain([minDate,maxDate])
              .range([0,width]);
  var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);
  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);

  var svg = 
  d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("height","100%").attr("width","100%");

  var margin = {left:50,right:50,top:40,bottom:0};

  var chartGroup = svg.append("g")
              .attr("transform","translate("+margin.left+","+margin.top+")");

  var line = d3.line()
                  .x(function(d){ return x(d.Year); })
                  .y(function(d){ return y(d.Price); });

  chartGroup.append("path").attr("d",line(data));
  chartGroup.append("g").attr("class","x 
  axis").attr("transform","translate(0,"+height+")").call(xAxis);
  chartGroup.append("g").attr("class","y axis").call(yAxis);

 })
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: If you are learing the basics of D3, as you claim, it might be worth digging into the latest version, which is **v6** instead of fiddling with an outdated version. Just saying.

Comment: Your problem is that the strings containing numbers having a comma as a thousands separator are not parseable as numbers. The easiest way is to just get rid of the comma before converting to a number: `Price: Number(typeof d.Price === "string" ? d.Price.replace(/,/g, "") : d.Price)`.